# Firmware unavailable for Netgate XG-7100

Tags: networking, firewall, freebsd, firmware, pfsense

I'm stuck with the firmware version 2.4.5 on this XG-7100 firewall and it seems that whatever branch or guide from netgate or thread I follow I cannot make pfSense to see a new firmware.

Current config:

```
2.4.5-RELEASE-p1 (amd64)
built on Tue Jun 02 17:51:54 EDT 2020
FreeBSD 11.3-STABLE
```

**CLI upgrade output**

pfSense-upgrade output:

```
>>> Updating repositories metadata...
pkg-static: Warning: Major OS version upgrade detected.  Running "pkg bootstrap -f" recommended
Updating pfSense-core repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.conf: . done
Fetching packagesite.pkg: . done
pkg-static: No trusted public keys found
Unable to update repository pfSense-core
Updating pfSense repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.conf: . done
Fetching packagesite.pkg: .......... done
pkg-static: No trusted public keys found
Unable to update repository pfSense
Error updating repositories!
>>> Upgrading pkg... failed.
```

pkg output:

```
Shared object "libarchive.so.7" not found, required by "pkg"
```

pkg_info output:

```
pkg_info: Command not found.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Netgate support as indicated by the first point of their firmware reinstall procedure? https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/solutions/xg-7100-1u/reinstall-pfsense.html

Comment: I was under the impression that support is paid only. Doing that now. Thanks.